# Android Unit Testing: calling function that uses viewModelScope causes a race condition

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-testing, robolectric

I have been trying to create unit tests on my viewModel, but every time I attempt to call a function that launches a coroutine with viewModelScope, it always ends up with a race condition.

example viewModel function:

```
fun doSomething () {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        runATask()
        flag = true
    }
}
```

the test I would make for this:

```
class viewModelTest {
    val testDispatcher = UnconfinedTestDispatcher()

    val viewModel = testViewModel()

    @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    @get:Rule
    var mainCoroutineRule = MainCoroutineRule(testDispatcher)

    @Test
    fun test_view_model () = runTest {
        viewModel.doSomething()

        assert(viewModel.flag == true)
    }
}
```

this would cause the viewModel function to start, but it does not complete once the test gets to the assertion.

I have tried following the android migration documentation for using runtest, using the MainCoroutineRule to set the main dispatcher to our UnconfinedTestDispatcher, and tried to launch the function call and join it. This race condition has occured on our instrumented tests and unit tests running robolectric.

I feel like I have tried every solution on StackOverflow that addresses this, and none of them have worked. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: tried runblockingTest?

Comment: runBlockingTest is deprecated